# Eclipse project facets in Maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, m2e-wtp

I'm starting to work with Maven in Eclipse but when I create a Maven project with several children projects, let's say:

```
-Maven project
   -Web project
   -EJB project
   -JSF project
```

Each of the children projects has a different set of facets in order for Eclipse enable the corresponding tooling.

The problem is that, when I import the Maven project, the children projects exists in the workspace (under the Maven project) as simple folders, so, no specific-tooling is available.

What is the correct way to work with Maven in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You need to "Import...>Existing Maven project". The import wizard will recursively discover all child modules (assuming they all have a pom.xml) and import them properly as separate Eclipse projects